# Unable to mount drive as read-write

Tags: arch-linux, mount, fstab, automounting

I have a 1TB HDD (`/dev/sda1`, mount point `/run/media/<name>/4733A97E4133EADF`) that I'm trying to mount as read-write, but I can only get it to mount as read-only.

System:

```
$ uname -a
Linux <hostname> 4.10.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Mar 27 08:28:22 CEST 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL       UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                            
└─sda1 ntfs               4733A97E4133EADF                     /run/media/<name>/4733A97E4133EADF
sdb                                                            
├─sdb1 swap               d9cea12d-5273-49ef-8950-3cd662fe63c7 [SWAP]
└─sdb2 ext4               e09a8578-53e9-4c26-9a97-a47b6350a1ab /
...
```

## What I've tried

- Adding a fstab entry to automount the drive on boot:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information
#
# <file system>                 <dir>                   <type>      <options>           <dump>  <pass>
# /dev/sdb2
UUID=e09a8578-53e9-4c26-9a97-a47b6350a1ab   /                       ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered    0   1

# /dev/sdb1
UUID=d9cea12d-5273-49ef-8950-3cd662fe63c7   none                    swap        defaults            0   0

# /dev/sda1
UUID=4733A97E4133EADF               /run/media/<name>/4733A97E4133EADF  ntfs        defaults,users,user     0   0
```

I've tried with `defaults`, `defaults,users`, and `defaults,users,user`. Rebooted after each change, but the drive is still mounted as read-only:

```
$ ls -l /run/media/<name>
...
dr-x------ 1 root  root  4096 Mar 28 17:35 4733A97E4133EADF
...
```

- Manually remounting:

```
$ sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda1 /run/media/<name>/4733A97E4133EADF
mount: cannot remount /dev/sda1 read-write, is write-protected
$ sudo umount /run/media/<name>/4733A97E4133EADF
$ sudo mount -o rw /dev/sda1 /run/media/<name>/4733A97E4133EADF
```

At this point, the command just hanged for a few minutes, so I terminated it.

```
$ sudo umount /run/media/<name>/4733A97E4133EADF
$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /run/media/<name>/4733A97E4133EADF
```

No change.

As of yet, I have not been able to write to the drive at all (from this system, at least), even as root.

`chown`, `chmod` have no effect because the filesystem is read-only.

---

What must I do to (auto)mount this drive as read-write, with normal (non-root) user access?

---

Have tried solutions from the following:

- [How do I remount a filesystem as read/write? | Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/175739/308918)
- [Ubuntu remount a root mount that's changed to ro as rw without rebooting | Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/q/678008)

Comment: The ntfs kernel driver does not support write access, use the ntfs-3g package.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although @ingopingo answered the question in one of the comments, i am going to write an answer with further information now.

By default the Linux kernel only supports reading from the NTFS file system. For read/write access you will need a read-write NTFS driver like the `ntfs-3g` package from `extra` repository.

After installation with `sudo pacman -S ntfs-3g` you are able to mount your NTFS partitions the usual way with `sudo mount /path/to/ntfs /mount/point`. This is possible due to a symlink of `/usr/bin/mount.ntfs` to `/usr/bin/ntfs-3g`.

> Note: You need to have root privilegs to mount the filesystem.
>   Requirements for an exception are listed in the [ntfs-3g-FAQ](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-faq/#useroption).

Using the default settings the NTFS-partition will be mounted at boot. Put the following in your `/etc/fstab`:

`/path/to/ntfs  /mount/point  ntfs-3g   defaults          0       0`

To be able to read-write with a non-root user, you have to set some additional options (username has to be changed to your username):

`/path/to/ntfs  /mount/point  ntfs-3g   uid=username,gid=users,umask=0022    0       0`

Answer (score 4):

I also had a read only mount problem and already used `ntfs-3g`. If someone else experiences this, check out `ntfsfix /dev/yourPartitionToMount`. It comes with the `ntfsprogs` under arch linux. This fixed my issue. I found it in the [arch linux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=104411)